# using conditional where in stored procedure of sql server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a condition in stored procedure which is created by using multiple tables. Can anybody please help me to solve this problem?

I want to skip a parameter if the parameter value is `null` or `nil`.

Example:
I want to see all the cities of a country starting with `'A'` if user select a country name from drop down list and want to see all the cities starting with `'A'` of all countries if user does not select any country.

Please suggest me what will be placed in the following line:-

```
WHERE substring(cityname,1,1)='A' and countryname=@countryname
```

Eagerly awaiting suggestion from anybody.

Thanks,
Nowshad

Answer (score 1):

> I want to skip a parameter if the parameter value is null

Simply check to see whether your parameters are `NULL` or whether they specify a predicate. If they specify a predicate, then check that it matches.

```
    SUBSTRING(CityName, 1, 1) = 'A'
AND ( @CountryName IS NULL OR CountryName = @CountryName )
```